# Set Background of Particular DataGrid Cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am looking to set the background color of a particular cell.  The row is getting selected in the code behind.  The IsSelected property doesn't seem to be working though the cell is getting selected in the code behind with the CurrentCell property of the dataGrid. Only works in form.

XAML:

```
 <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">  
        <Style.Triggers> 
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">  
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" /> 
            </Trigger> 
        </Style.Triggers> 
    </Style>
```

Code:

```
dg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dg.Items[0],dg.Columns[0]);

dg.CellStyle = this.FindResource("CellStyle") as Style;
```

Comment: have you tried using an EventTrigger for the IsSelected property?

Comment: does your FindResource call result in a Style or null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

You can set the cell style in xaml:

```
<DataGrid CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}"
```

And then:

```
   var dataGridCellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(dataGrid.Items[0], dataGrid.Columns[0]);
   dataGrid.SelectedCells.Clear();
   dataGrid.SelectedCells.Add(dataGridCellInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working.  Is it possible to have it leave the cell highlighted once focus is lost?

Comment: nvm... commented out the Clear... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this example code, it works for me

```
public Window8() {
  this.InitializeComponent();

  this.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                      var cellStyle = this.FindResource("CellStyle") as Style;
                      this.dg.CellStyle = cellStyle;
                      this.dg.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    };
}

<Window.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="CellStyle"
          TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Yellow" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="Black" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>

</Window.Resources>
```

**NOTE**

the style is applied to all cells!

hope this helps